# MySQL IF NOT NULL, then display 1, else display 0

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I'm working with a little display complication here.  I'm sure there's an IF/ELSE capability I'm just overlooking.

I have 2 tables I'm querying (customers, addresses).  The first has the main record, but the second may or may not have a record to LEFT JOIN to.

I want to display a zero if there is no record in the addresses table. 
And I want to only display 1, if a record exists.

What I've attempted so far:

```
SELECT c.name, COALESCE(a.addressid,0) AS addressexists
FROM customers c
LEFT JOIN addresses a ON c.customerid = a.customerid
WHERE customerid = 123
```

This first example does not do it.  But I may be utilizing COALESCE wrong.

How can I display a 0, if null, and a 1, if something exists?

Answer (score 262, accepted):

Instead of `COALESCE(a.addressid,0) AS addressexists`, use `CASE`:

```
CASE WHEN a.addressid IS NOT NULL 
       THEN 1
       ELSE 0
END AS addressexists
```

or the simpler:

```
(a.addressid IS NOT NULL) AS addressexists
```

This works because `TRUE` is displayed as `1` in MySQL and `FALSE` as `0`.

Comment: how about `IFNULL(column, '')` ,  there is any short for if not null ?

Comment: @YogiArifWidodo not sure what exactly you are asking. In most cases, if not all, you can do what you want with a CASE expression.

Answer (score 126):

```
SELECT c.name, IF(a.addressid IS NULL,0,1) AS addressexists
FROM customers c
LEFT JOIN addresses a ON c.customerid = a.customerid
WHERE customerid = 123
```

Answer (score 24):

Careful if you're coming from C/C++ and expecting this to work:

```
select if(name, 1, 0) ..
```

Even if 'name' is not NULL, unlike in C, a false-condition still triggers and the above statement returns 0. Thus, you have to remember to explicitly check for NULL or empty string:

```
 select if(name is null or name = '', 0, 1)
```

*PS [Eugen's example up above is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9387875/2949533), but I wanted to clarify this nuance as it caught me by surprise.*

Comment: "if(name is null or name = '', 0, 1)" Yes. need add condition name = ''. It's working well

Answer (score 23):

```
SELECT 
    c.name, 
    CASE WHEN a.addressid IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS addressexists
FROM customers c
LEFT JOIN addresses a ON c.customerid = a.customerid
WHERE customerid = 123
```

Answer (score 5):

Another method without WHERE, try this..

Will select both Empty and NULL values

```
SELECT ISNULL(NULLIF(fieldname,''))  FROM tablename
```

It will set null if it is an empty string, then be true on that also.

Comment: Also useful:     select IFNULL(fieldname, "1") from tablename;

Answer (score 5):

If within TSQL, you can try :

```
SELECT IF(a.addressid IS NULL, 0, 1) AS addressexists
```

SQL Server should work

Answer (score 5):

You can actually use an IF statement in the latest versions of MySQL.

```
IF(expr,if_true_expr,if_false_expr)
```

IE:

```
SELECT name, IF(ISNULL(name), 'robot', 'human') AS type
FROM visitors
```