# Mysql update which skips or ignore the fields that are not required

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, sql-update

I have a sample database with given fields.

What i am trying to achieve is to do an update query on sql that skips field that i am not interested to update.

```
UPDATE `nmc_cd` SET `CDID`=[value-1],`CDTitle`=[value-2],`CDYear`=[value-3],`pubID`=[value-4],`catID`=[value-5],`CDPrice`=[value-6] WHERE 1
```

This is the syntax i was provided.

I manage to update one single column with this query

```
UPDATE `nmc_cd` SET `CDTitle`= 'Black President01' WHERE `CDID` = 978
```

But when i try to use the syntax to update just a field and ignore the rest everything goes haywire

```
UPDATE `nmc_cd` SET `CDTitle`='Black President01',`pubID`="",`catID`="",`CDPrice`="" WHERE `CDID` = 653
```

This will update the title and replace the other fields in "" with an empty or blank field in the database.

The next best thing was using NULL

```
UPDATE `nmc_cd` SET `CDTitle`='Black President03',`pubID`="NULL",`catID`="NULL",`CDPrice`="" WHERE `CDID` = 653
```

and it returned me with the updated Black President03 but the rest of the field was replaced with NULL ;(

Is there such a method to update and ignoring the field if it has already been filled ?

I know the obvious answer is to just omit out the fields which i do not require to update but i have a form in html which dynamically populates the results.
See pic attached.

[html form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaSKL.png)

I was thinking of doing an sql query to just update the field that has changed and leave the rest as it is.

I could do an if else on php but it would be tedious.

Is there another simpler method to resolve this problem ?

Thank you in advance for your kind advice.

Cheers !

Answer (score 1):

You could make a custom query with low effort and a few if's.

```php
query = "UPDATE `nmc_cd` SET";

if (title filled) query += " `CDTitle`= 'title_value',";
if (pub filled) query += " `pubID`= 'pub value',";
if (cat filled) query += " `catID`= 'cat value',";
if (price filled) query += " `CDPrice`= 'price value',";

//Substring to trim the comma. You should check at least 1 field is filled
query = substr(query, 0, strlen(query) -1) + " WHERE `CDID` = '653';"
```

Answer (score 0):

The method you are looking for is "IF NOT NULL".
But in your case just leave the attributes you won't update away ;)

Comment: This would only replace the field with IF NOT NULL. The form already has data populated. So there has to be a field i need to include in the query.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387839/mysql-if-not-null-then-display-1-else-display-0

Answer (score 0):

The fastest and easiest way is You could just resubmit the form values into the database.

If that is not appealing than you could just use a switch case to build query depending on what data is coming in. Presuming you have to store the previous data to compare the data which has been changed or use JS to identfy and onchange ...

The other sql solution is (psudecode) but you should be able to figure it out with this

```
UPDATE nmc_cd
    IF(CDYear='value')    
    (
        SET CDYear= 1   
    )
    ELSE
    (
         ...
    )
    ENDIF
WHERE CDIDIS = 653
```

more information
https://bytes.com/topic/mysql/answers/898785-mysql-how-use-update-if-else-condition

Comment: The fastest and easiest way is You could just resubmit the form values into the database. This would be easy if i had just one table. However i have 3 different tables. To join in an update query which is a headache.