# MySQL Node.js Query Ends, no Callback

Tags: mysql, node.js, mysqljs

I'm using `mysql` for node.js.

This query checks if a column has all `NULL` values, by checking if at least one row is not `NULL`.

```sql
SELECT 1 FROM `table` WHERE `column` IS NOT NULL LIMIT 1
```

If the column has all `NULL` values, this query ends in the SQL processlist after a few seconds (~120), but I never get a callback from the js code:

```
import {createPool as mysqlCreatePool, MysqlError} from 'mysql';

const db = mysqlCreatePool({...})

const query = db.query(sql, undefined, function (err: MysqlError | null, res?: any) {
  console.log(err, res);
});

query.on('end', () => console.log("end"));
```

(Nothing is ever printed in the console)

Answer (score 1):

Might not be the same approach but will get you the answer I think you're after and always return a result.

Query for a `count` rather than a fixed value and use `IS NULL` rather than `IS NOT NULL`:

```sql
SELECT count(*) AS null_count FROM `table` WHERE `column` IS NULL;
```

If your response is `0` every record has a value for that column. If your response is greater than `0` you have that many records with a `NULL` value in that column.

Comment: I understand how this will always get a result, but, this is much more expensive time-wise, as the other method is negation based (NOT NULL LIMIT 1) and works really fast. Any idea specifically why my query doesn't return anything on nodejs musql?

Comment: You could try a variation of the `CASE WHEN` approach. I'm not familiar with the performance impact compared to my prior example and your original. Consider this approach: `SELECT (column IS NOT NULL) AS null_check FROM table LIMIT 1`. Testing each of the 3 variations on a remote DB table with ~120k records, all have a similar response time of appx. 16ms to 18ms. More details here on the alternate approach : (https://stackoverflow.com/a/9387864/1720873)